# Changing the size of seaborn pairplot markers

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a seaborn.pairplot with small dots like this one:
[image]

But I get one with the markers much bigger and I can't find how to change their size in the documentation. My pairplot looks like this:

[image]

The code I'm using to plot is:

```
sns.pairplot(df, diag_kind='kde')
sns.plt.show()
```

Comment: Final example here: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html

Comment: Thanks, @mwaskom. Do you know where I can find the rest of the arguments for `plot_kws`?

Comment: They are arguments for whatever function is being used to plot in the upper and lower triangle. (In this case, `plt.scatter`).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Adding this should solve the issue - just worked for me

```
plot_kws={"s": 3}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to clarify the above answer in that plot_kws = {"s":3} is a dictionary with size ("s") set to the value of 3. You can increase or decrease the value as you like. For example you can do plot_kws = {"s":1}.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, the given did not fix the problem since the `plot_kws` parameter given to `sns.pairplot` is forwarded ro `sns.regplot`, which itself accepts a `scatter_kws` argument, which in the end is passed to `plt.scatter()` and actually draws the scatter plot.

Very nested, but

`sns.pairplot(data, kind="reg", plot_kws=dict(scatter_kws=dict(s=3)))`

should work.

Credits should go [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56876841/23382601), where Diziet answered it.