# Change marker size in seaborn pairplot with kind reg

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I want to reduce marker size in seaborn 0.9.0 pairplot using `kind = 'reg'`

I have tried:

```
sns.pairplot(a_dataframe, kind="reg", s=1)
TypeError: pairplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 's'

sns.pairplot(a_dataframe, kind="reg", scatter_kws={'s':2})
pairplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scatter_kws'

sns.pairplot(a_dataframe, kind="reg", plot_kws=dict(s=1))
regplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'plot_kws'
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to chain the kwargs, first [to pass them on to `sns.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html?highlight=pairplot#seaborn-pairplot), which is used to plot the off-diagonal plots. `sns.regplot` itself [accepts a `scatter_kws=`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) argument to be passed to `plt.scatter()` which is the function that actually draws the scatter plot.

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris, kind="reg", plot_kws=dict(scatter_kws=dict(s=2)))
```

[image]